# eXist: is it possible to have XQuery modules stored in XML files?

Tags: module, xquery, exist-db

You can store a module in eXist, such as the following, say under `/modules/my.xqm`:

```
module namespace my = "http://www.example.com/";
declare function my:answerToTheUltimateQuestion() as xs:integer { 42 }
```

And then import it into a query, such as:

```
import module namespace my="http://www.example.com/" 
                        at "xmldb:exist:///db/modules/my.xqm";
my:answerToTheUltimateQuestion()
```

Instead of storing the XQuery in a "text file", is it possible to store it in an XML file, which would just be a wrapper around the XQuery? I am thinking about a wrapper similar to the one we use when POSTing queries to eXist (`<exist:query><exist:text>`). This would make it easier to manipulate XQuery modules with tools that expects XML data stored in the database.

Answer (score 3):

You could store your XQuery in XQueryX format into eXist-db and then use a small XQuery and the XSLT from the XQueryX W3C spec within eXist-db to transform this into XQuery and execute it.

Comment: Adam, thank you for the advice. So I've got my XML file that contains the XQuery for the module in `module.xml`: `<module>XQuery for module</module>`. At the beginning, I add: `<?xml-stylesheet href="to-xquery.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>`. When I do a GET for `module.xml`, it gets processed by the XSLT, and I get back the XQuery. The only issue is that the content type is text/html, instead of application/xquery. I added an `<xsl:output method="text" media-type="application/xquery"/>` to the XSLT, but this doesn't seem to have an effect on the content type. Am I missing something?